# Grails relationship reference despite having a belongsTo

Tags: grails

Let's say an `Owned` domain class belongs to an `Owner` domain class by having this declaration in its body:

```
static belongsTo [ Owner ]
```

Why then in some cases do I still see the `Owned` domain class also having a property or field like reference to the `Owner` domain class like

```
Owner owner
```

despite having the belongsTo clause in its body? Wouldn't the `belongsTo` declaration take care of the needed reference in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of

```
static belongsTo = [ Owner ]
```

and

```
Owner owner
```

is essentially the same as

```
static belongsTo = [owner: Owner ]
```

because using the map form triggers (via an AST transformation) the creation of a property of type `Owner` with name `owner`.

My preference is to use the single statement however because it's the standard way to declare a bidirectional one-many and the other way feels like a side effect.

One reason that using the simpler form of `belongsTo` and declaring the owner property is when you have multiple parent domain classes, but some are bidirectional and some aren't, e.g.

```
static belongsTo = [Owner, OtherClass]
Owner owner
```

This way you make `Owner`/`Owned` bidirectional, but leave the `OtherClass` relationship unidirectional.

Comment: burt, your explanations are always beyond the question. nice. but one question is it mandatory to specify owner in many to many r/ship.

Comment: Yes, one of the domain classes has to be the owner, in part to link the two one-to-many (`hasMany`) properties. In practice it doesn't affect much though.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Can this static belongsTo = [Owner, OtherClass] and 
Owner owner also be accomplished as belongsTo = [OtherClass] and then in the same class having  belongsTo = [owner:Owner]. That would mean two belongsTo declarations in the same domain class to accomplish the same selective bidirectionality as in your example towards the end of your answer. Or would this just be too ugly and considered bad practice?

Comment: You can't have two properties with the same name